# Plot display two items with same label (two lines, only one label) ggplot R facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to have two distinct lines with values for an object named identically but differs on something else. 
It should only have one line of text.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
#gen some example code
c <- c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b')
d <- c('firstfirst', 'firstfirst', 'lowerupper', 'lowerlower')
e <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
f <- c('w', 'v','w', 'v')
df <- cbind(c,d,e,f)
df<- as.data.frame(df)
df$e <- as.numeric(df$e)
orderd <- c( 'firstfirst', 'firstfirst', 'lowerupper', 'lowerlower' )
df<- within(df, d <- factor(d, levels=orderd))


ggplot(df, aes(x = d, y = e, color = f)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(min = e - 1.95 * sqrt(e), max = e + 1.95 * sqrt(e)), shape = 15) +
  theme_bw() + 
  facet_wrap(c ~ .,  nrow = 5, strip.position = "left") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_colour_viridis_d(begin = 0.75 , end = 0) +
  geom_text(aes(label = f), colour = "black", size = 2.5, hjust=1.05, vjust=1.2)
```

In the graph, I want on both panels just one line saying "firstfirst" but I want to have TWO lines, one in case f = v and one for f=w.

My current work around is to label one of it "firstfirst " (i.e. having an additional blank space). However, this just produces two lines, see example here:

How would it be possible to have the text only once but having both lines?

Bonus points if it is easily reproducible for multiple graphs of this kind!

The picture shows what I want (edited outside of R). [image: The picture shows what I want (edited outside of R)]

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is probably to work with position_dodge. Taking your example code, you could thus simply add the position_dodge command to geom_pointrange

```
 geom_pointrange(aes(min = e - 1.95 * sqrt(e), max = e + 1.95 * sqrt(e)), shape = 15, position = position_dodge(width=1))
```

[resulting in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzrbL.png)

Comment: Thank you! This is generously helpful. How would I go about if I have only 2 that should be separated by a position dodge and 2 which should be on the very same line? (All 4 have the same name in terms of "d", they only differ by a second variable not introduced in this example yet.